# How can I merge 2 branches in my local repository

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have 2 branches in my hg repository:
1. default 
2. new-feature

I tried following this: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NamedBranches,
I switch back to default by 'hg update -c default'
but how can I merge my commits in 'new-feature' to 'default'.

I did "hg pull new-feature", it said "repository new-feature not found"!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are on the `default` branch (with `hg update default`), just do:

```
hg merge new-feature
```

This command will merge the `new-feature` branch on the `default` one. If there are any conflict, Mercurial will tell you.